# Problem accessing AppSettings via configSource in Windows Server 2003

Tags: .net, windows-server-2003, configsource

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx), `configSource` is supported on Windows Server 2003 SP2. However, when I try to access a setting using the following syntax:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SettingName"];
```

then `null` is returned. However, the same app works properly on Windows 7 and Windows XP (i.e. `AppSettings["SettingName"]` returns the expected value when using `configSource`).

The file that `configSource` points to exists for sure, since I copied the entire application directory from Windows 7 to Server 2003 for testing.

Any ideas?

Comment: You've tried this with permissions wide open and/or running the app as an admin? (just to help narrow things down; not advocating for this!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an incomplete application manifest file.  You need to add the "assemblyIdentity" element.  Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/junfeng/application-config-file-is-not-used-if-the-application-has-certain-sxs-manifest).  There is also an MS Connect bug [here](https://www.bing.com/?ref=aka&shorturl=connect-redirect).

Comment: You must be psychic. +1 Thanks!